# error C2039: 'update' : is not a member of

Tags: c++, sfml, объявление

Создал класс Player, далее его параметр, после этого создал процедуру обновления координат игрока, компилирую - выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Error 35  error C2039: 'update' : is not a member of 'Player' c:\users\livolickie\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\sfml\sfml\main.cpp    103 1   SFML

Сам код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;

class Player
{
public:
    float x,y,w,h,dx,dy,speed;
    int dir;
    String File;
    Image image;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;

    Player(String F, float X, float Y, float W, float H)
    {
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        speed = 0;
        dir = 0;

        File = F;
        w = W;
        h = H;
        image.loadFromFile("textures/"+File);
        image.createMaskFromColor(Color(41,33,59));
        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0,0,w,h));
    }
}

void update(float time)
{
    switch(dir)
    {
    case 0: dx = speed; dy = 0; break;
    case 1: dx = -speed; dy = 0; break;
    case 2: dx = 0; dy = speed; break;
    case 3: dx = 0; dy = -speed; break;
    }

    x += dx*time;
    y += dy*time;

    speed = 0;
    sprite.setPosition(x,y);
}

int main()
{
    Player p("hero.png",250,250,96.0,96.0);
    RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Test");
    Clock clock;
    float c_frame;
    c_frame = 0;
    while (window.isOpen()) 
    {
        float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
        clock.restart();
        time = time/800;
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //Управление игроком
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W))
        {
            p.dir = 3; p.speed = 0.1;
            c_frame += 0.005*time;
            if (c_frame >3) c_frame = 0;
            p.sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(96*int(c_frame),288,96,96));
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
        {
            p.dir = 1; p.speed = 0.1;
            c_frame += 0.005*time;
            if (c_frame >3) c_frame = 0;
            p.sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(96*int(c_frame),96,96,96));
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S))
        {
            p.dir = 2; p.speed = 0.1;
            c_frame += 0.005*time;
            if (c_frame >3) c_frame = 0;
            p.sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(96*int(c_frame),0,96,96));
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
        {
            p.dir = 0; p.speed = 0.1;
            c_frame += 0.005*time;
            if (c_frame >3) c_frame = 0;
            p.sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(96*int(c_frame),192,96,96));
        }

        p.update(time);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(p.sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Но у вас и в самом деле `update` - свободная функция, а не член класса. Внесите ее в класс, а после объявления класса не забудьте, кстати, точку с запятой :)

Comment: вообще не заметил про этом, спасибо вам)

Comment: Мой совет - форматируйте код, тогда такие вещи будут видны сразу.

Answer (score 5):

У вас определение класса не завершено. Во-первых, у вас нет точки с запятой после определения класса,

```
class Player
{
    //...
} <== должна быть точка с запятой
```

а, во-вторых, функция `update` объявлена вне класса, следовательно не является членом класса. То есть полученное вами сообщение об ошибке является следствием других синтаксических ошибок.

Попутное замечание: член класса `dir` лучше объявить как перечисление. А иначе не ясно, что это за магические значения, которые вы проверяете в switch предложении. Так же не ясно, почему у вас все члены класса являются открытыми.